# Grant a login of Sql server authentication the same permission of a Windows group login with Windows authentication?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, permissions, security, logins

**Update:**
I am trying to make it easier for the login to have the permissions on multiple databases.

I already have a Windows group login with Windows authentication. The Windows users in the group can access *multiple* databases on a server.

Now I need to create an Sql server login and I want it have the same permission of the Windows group login (so it will have the permissions on mulitple database). Is it possible to do it without grant all the permissions to the SQL server separately?

I tried to create a credential for the Windows group login and add the credential to the SQL login but it doesn't work.

```
create credential WinGroupLogin with identity = 'MyServer\WinGroupLogin'
ALTER LOGIN [sql_login] ADD CREDENTIAL [WinGroupLogin]
```

Answer (score 2):

At the database level, you could simply add both to the same [database role](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187936(v=sql.100).aspx). Of course, when you create the role, you'll have to grant it all the same permissions as the existing group, but you only have to do that once.

At the server level, to do that without re-applying all of the permissions (which you could probably script without a whole lot of effort - [you can get some ideas here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1987190/scripting-sql-server-permissions)), you'll have to wait for SQL Server 2012, unless you can use a fixed server role.

Comment: The login needs to inherit permissions on multiple databases. I'm trying to not create database users on these DBs too.

Comment: So you want a server-level login to inherit database-level permissions on multiple databases without creating database users? Well, I fold.

Comment: I've been doing this by creating Windows group login so I can add the Windows users to the group. I thought the `credential` can make Sql login inherit the permissions of the group.

Comment: I don't know of a way, but I am asking a friend who should know one way or another.

Comment: You shouldn't be granting privileges to users directly IMHO.  If you granted privileges to a role and added whoever needs those privileges to the appropriate roles you would solve your problem easily. I faced the same problem in the past and learned my lesson the hard way. It could look like overkill at the beginning, but saves a lot of work in the long run. Login means identity, SQL/Windows means authentication, role means authorization.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to do this automatically.  As they are separate logins the permissions must be applied separately to each one granting them rights into the specific databases that they need rights to.